# Identify which set these parts are from

Tags: set-identification

[image: Lego parts that was donated]

Help identify if these parts belong to a set.It was donated to us and it would be great if we could use instructionsto build

Answer (score 5):

These parts are from

[75202-1: Defense of Crait](https://brickset.com/sets/75202-1/Defense-of-Crait)
[image]

Based on the [Windscreen 6 x 4 x 1 Curved with Gray Star Wars Skimmer Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18973pb08#T=C&C=13)